# How to index only document content and not document property in text field in Apache Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using Apache Solr 8.6 to index the documents using POST Tool in Linux as mentioned in the [Apache Solr Reference Guide](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/about-this-guide.html).

POST Tool Command

```
bin/post -c testcore /testdocs/
```

The documents are getting indexed successfully. Now when I searched the string eg: hello in Solr Admin UI, It is returning the matching documents and also i can view the document content in `_text_` field as i have used  below property to store the content in **manage-schema.xml**

```
<field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

**It is indexing the document content and storing in `_text_` field but it is also storing and displaying the document property like content-type and other document type properties in `_text_` field.**

Now i want that these properties should not get stored in `_text_` field and only actual document content should be stored.

**solrconfig.xml configuration**

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" startup="lazy" class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler">

 <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="lowernames">true</str>
      <str name="fmap.meta">ignored_</str>
      <str name="fmap.content">_text_</str>
    </lst>

</requestHandler>
```

Will be grateful if you could guide me further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the parameter `uprefix` instead of `fmap.<source_field>` in order to map unknown field names to a schema field name which will be ignored (you can use fmap only to map known field names), so in the request handler you should have :

```
<str name="uprefix">ignored_</str>
```

The corresponding dynamic field must be defined in the schema to handle these unknown fields (and the fieldType as well, don't know if it's already there when using a managed-schema) :

```
<dynamicField name="ignored_*" type="ignored" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have replaced uprefix instead of fmap.<source_field>. Also in managed-schema.xml it already has the desired field. But when i reindex the document it is still showing like " \n \n stream_size 11476  \n X-Parsed-By org.apache.tika.parser.DefaultParser \n X-Parsed-By org.apache.tika.parser.pkg.PackageParser  \n stream_content_type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document  \n resourceName test16m.docx  \n Content-Type application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument" etc in the text field and then the actual document content

Comment: actually document property fields like "x_parsed_by,stream_content_type" which are present in the managed-schema.xml are getting indexed and stored in _text_ field also.I need to exclude those fields and include only document content in this _text_ field.

Comment: Ok I see, you need `<str name="captureAttr">true</str>` (this is the default value only to ensure solr does not map all meta to the content field), then either you comment out the tika fields that are defined in the schema (so that they are mapped dynamically to ignored_* via "uprefix" parameter), either you explicitly map them to ignored_ or a dedicated field via fmap (eg. `<str name="fmap.x_parsed_by">ignored_</str>`).